# Passing IIS Basic Authentication to SQL Server in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp.net-core, basic-authentication

A little background for this question:

I've got an ASP.NET Intranet application that accesses sensitive data in an MS SQL Server database. Because of the nature of the data, the database table itself is locked down to only select users. We're using Basic Authentication in IIS and impersonation in order to use integrated security when accessing the data.

All of that works fine, but we're now in the process of converting our Intranet site to .NET Core. I understand that impersonation of the sort we're using isn't directly supported in Core, but are there any options or workarounds available that would make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options for you:

1. Try `WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated` which will use the current user identity to login to sql server.

   ```
       public IActionResult About()
   {
       IList<Blog> blogs = new List<Blog>();
       var user = (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity;
       WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(user.AccessToken, () =>
       {
           var impersonatedUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
           blogs = _context.Blogs.ToList();
       });
       return Ok(blogs);

       //_context
       //ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

       //return View();
   }
   ```
2. You could run the .net core project under the user account in iis which has permission to access sql server, then check the user identity to see whether he has permission to access the sql server dynamically before he access the controller which will call db action method.

Comment: The first option was unfortunately not an option owing to how we have authentication set up for the site as a whole, but the second option is a good workaround to bypass the issue entirely. Thanks.